# karate Gatling - How to simulate simultaneous load for different accounts

Tags: karate

I want to test a load test scenario where many users do the login simultaneously.

I gave those login credentials in scenario outline, which is wrong as it will execute the login process in sequential manner.

Do we have a way by which I can run this login process simultaneously for various users?

Below is my feature and scala file. Here I gave 3 users but there are 100 users to be tested for simultaneous login.

**Feature file**

```
Feature: Login for users

  Scenario Outline: login for -  <accountNumber>
   
    * def myAccountNumber = <accountNumber>
    * def myCardNumber = <cardNumber>

Given url baseUrl+'/session/loginchallenge?accountNumber='+myAccountNumber+'&cardNumber='+myCardNumber
And header Authorization = call read('classpath:basic-auth.js'){ username: '#(username)', password: '#(password)' }
When method GET
Then status 200

 Examples:
      | accountNumber | cardNumber |
      | 491081000     | 123        | 
      | 106807111     | 999        | 
      | 102005222     | 090        |
```

**Scala file:**

```
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

class PerfPushDevicesBulk extends Simulation {

  before {
    println("Perf tests started")
  }

 
  val getTest1 = scenario("Login  for 100 different users").exec(karateFeature("classpath:features/Performance/LoginPerformance.feature"))
 
  setUp(

    getTest1.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  

  ).assertions(
    global.responseTime.max.lt(2000)

  )

  after {
    println("Perf tests ended")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need different Gatling `scenario`s. Refer to the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling/#usage

And you probably need to use "feeders": https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling/#feeders

So you can use multiple Karate features and for each feature you can have different numbers of users simultaneously. It may mean you re-design your tests a bit. You can target one row of a `Scenario Outlime` via a tag if you really want but this is rare: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#tags-and-examples